# Why do I get an error: error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: typescript

I try to compile this simple code:

```
class C {
    @log
    foo(n: number) {
        return n * 2;
    }
}

function log(target: Function, key: string, value: any) {
    return {
        value: function (...args: any[]) {
            var a = args.map(a => JSON.stringify(a)).join();
            var result = value.value.apply(this, args);
            var r = JSON.stringify(result);
            console.log(`Call: ${key}(${a}) => ${r}`);
            return result;
        }
    };
}
```

When compile I get an error: **error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.**

What is the cause of the error?

Comment: what line are you getting this error on

Comment: I found the solution - it works if compile with "--target ES5" option:  `tsc --target ES5 --experimentalDecorators example.ts`

Answer (score 0):

The parameters that the decorator function receives should be different, as noted [in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators):

```
function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor)
```

In your code `target` is of type `Function` and so the compiler complains that:

> Argument of type 'C' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Function'.
>   Property 'apply' is missing in type 'C'.

If you change it to `any` like in the docs then it works, you can also change it to `C` but then it will work only with class `C` and not other classes.
Also, you can fix up your decorator function a bit, because you are returning a descriptor with only the `value` property.
Instead, you better copy the previous descriptor and change the `value` on that:

```
function log(target: C, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    let newDescriptor: PropertyDescriptor = Object.assign({}, descriptor);
    newDescriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
        var a = args.map(a => JSON.stringify(a)).join();
        var result = descriptor.value.apply(this, args);
        var r = JSON.stringify(result);
        console.log(`Call: ${key}(${a}) => ${r}`);
        return result;
    }

    return newDescriptor;
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%40log%0A%20%20%20%20foo(n%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20n%20*%202%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20log(target%3A%20C%2C%20key%3A%20string%2C%20descriptor%3A%20PropertyDescriptor)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20newDescriptor%3A%20PropertyDescriptor%20%3D%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20descriptor)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20newDescriptor.value%20%3D%20function%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20a%20%3D%20args.map(a%20%3D%3E%20JSON.stringify(a)).join()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20result%20%3D%20descriptor.value.apply(this%2C%20args)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20r%20%3D%20JSON.stringify(result)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%60Call%3A%20%24%7Bkey%7D(%24%7Ba%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%24%7Br%7D%60)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20result%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20newDescriptor%3B%0A%7D))

Comment: Well, I created a file "example.ts" and inserted this fixed code into it

When I try to compile it: tsc example.ts --experimentalDecorators
I get this error: 

example.ts(2,5): error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
example.ts(9,52): error TS2339: Property 'assign' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.

Comment: still does not work:

*example.ts*: 

`class C {
    @log
    foo(n: number) {
        return n * 2;
    }
}

function log(target: any, key: any, value: any) {
    return {
        value: function (...args: any[]) {
            console.log('this is a method decorator');
            return value.value.apply(this, args);
        }
    };
}
`

**>tsc example.ts --experimentalDecorators**

example.ts(2,5): error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Comment: 1. Don't put this much code in a comment, instead edit your question and add the code and write the problem, then comment and ask to check your revised question.  2. this code works for me with no compilation errors. 3. As I wrote, you better copy the old descriptor, change the `value` and return that instead of returning a descriptor with only the `value` property

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice about descriptor.
I wonder why I get an error.. I guess something wrong in my environment but what?

Comment: Try to reproduce your error in playground, if you manage to do so, then add that playground link to your question and update me here as a comment

Comment: I found the solution - it works if compile with "--target ES5" option:  `tsc --target ES5 --experimentalDecorators example.ts`